# Prevent usage of a third-party base class

Tags: c++, std

I have implemented my own wrapper around `std::chrono::steady_clock` and would like to prevent any other developer from using the original:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

namespace my_chrono {
    class MyClock : public std::chrono::steady_clock {
        // stuff here...
    };
}

int main()
{
    auto my_now = my_chrono::MyClock::now();                // this should compile
    auto chrono_now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();     // this should be prevented

    std::cout << my_now.time_since_epoch().count() << ", " << chrono_now.time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to force usage of `MyClock` over `steady_clock` (for example via compiler errors or warnings treated as errors).

Comment: You basically can't.  This is part of what code review is for.

Comment: I have some ideas, but all of them require a way to include arbitrary code in every translation unit that you want this to work for (probably by adding an `-include foo.h` flag). Is that ok?

Comment: Honestly, what is the use-case for preventing this?  The programmers now have to learn new functions and trust your class code, instead of using the well-documented, peer-reviewed, easily researched, functions in the `<chrono>` class.

Comment: if your class has clear benefits over, `std::chrono::steady_clock` ppl will use it. If not why should they?

Comment: Is it possible that this question is sprouting from an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? *Why* do you want to prevent the user from using `std::chrono::steady_clock` and force them to use your class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make it impossible for some other code to be unable to use something you have no control over. And the C++ standard library is something over which you have no control.